# How to fit an image of any aspect ratio into fullscreen popup div?

Tags: html, css

TASK: I have a photo gallery with thumbnails. Clicking on the thumbnail should display and fit the image fullscreen centered without losing aspect ratio and without hiding any parts of the image outside the browser's window. This should work for any image aspect ratios (square, rectangles x>y and x<y). The solution should work without changing any head or body css (project independent).

WHAT I HAVE: works with horizontal images where dimensions x>y. Problems with square and vertical images, a scrollbar appears and the image doesn't fit fullscreen. Could someone help me out, been struggling for 2nd day already.

DEMO:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.photo-overlay').hide();
  $('.thumb').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var imageUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.photo-overlay').show();
    $('.photo-content').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');

  });
  $('.photo-overlay').click(function(event) {
    $('.photo-overlay').hide();
  });

});
```

```css
.photo-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  z-index: 2211;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.photo-content{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position:absolute;
}

.imgBox {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="photo-wrapper" align="center">
    <div class="photo-content" align="center">
        <img src="" style="visibility: hidden; max-height:100%; max-width:100%" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="imgBox">
    <a  class="thumb" href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/11/22/40/seamless-pattern-2740688_960_720.png">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/11/22/40/seamless-pattern-2740688_960_720.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this fiddle: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/b4d6wfhe/2/)

It gives the results I was looking for!

```
.full-screen {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/150x350) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
}

<div class="full-screen">
</div>
```